# How to do Spring batch record partition on large file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

How to do Spring batch record partition on large file?

Example say if I have 100 records in file, I need to improve spring batch processing speed creating 1 thread  each 10 records. How to do it? Currently I am using MultiResourcePartitioner. But this partitioner creating partition per file. So no performance impact on one large file. How to do it?

Yes I need to write custom partition like https://mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-partitioning-example/ but nothing working. need help

```
Thread 1 - Process from 1 to 10
Thread 2 - Process from 11 to 20
Thread 3 - Process from 21 to 30
......
Thread 9 - Process from 81 to 90
Thread 10 - Process from 91 to 100
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi I resolved this problem myself by splitting File to smaller chunks and use the MultiResourcePartitioner to  read chunk files.

Comment: the example you were checking is a range columns partitioner. so i think in that case, identifiers must bellow to the ranges speciefied above. if not, partitioner will not work as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I resolved this problem myself by splitting File to smaller chunks and use the MultiResourcePartitioner to read chunk files.

This is below is my splitter program

```
package com.cookmedical.batch.utils;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class FileSplitter {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileSplitter.class);
    public static String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public static int MAX_FILE_RECORDS = 50;

    public void split(File masterFile) throws IOException {
        try {
            // opens the file in a string buffer

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(masterFile));
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            // performs the splitting
            String fileLine;
            int fileLineNumber = 0;
            int rowCounter = 0;
            int partitionCounter = 1;
            String fileHeader = "";
            String parentFolder = masterFile.getParent();
            String fileName = StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(masterFile.getName(), ".csv") + "_";
            while ((fileLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                if (fileLineNumber == 0) {
                    fileHeader = fileLine;
                }

                if (rowCounter >= MAX_FILE_RECORDS) {
                    saveFilePartition(parentFolder, fileName+partitionCounter+".csv",masterFile.lastModified(),stringBuffer);
                    rowCounter = 0;
                    partitionCounter++;
                    stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                    stringBuffer.append(fileHeader);
                    stringBuffer.append(NEWLINE);
                    stringBuffer.append(fileLine);
                    stringBuffer.append(NEWLINE);
                } else {
                    stringBuffer.append(fileLine);
                    stringBuffer.append(NEWLINE);
                }

                rowCounter++;
                fileLineNumber++;
            }
            saveFilePartition(parentFolder, fileName+partitionCounter+".csv",masterFile.lastModified(),stringBuffer);
            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void saveFilePartition(String parentFolder, String fileName, long lastModifiedTime, StringBuffer fileContent) throws IOException {
        File splitFolder = new File(parentFolder + File.separator + "splitFolder");
        splitFolder.mkdir();

        FileWriter output = null;
        try {
            splitFolder = new File(splitFolder + File.separator + fileName);

            splitFolder.setLastModified(lastModifiedTime);
            output = new FileWriter(splitFolder);
            output.write(fileContent.toString());
            // System.out.println("file " + file.getAbsolutePath() +
            // " written");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // do nothing the file wasn't been even opened
            }
        }
    }

}
```